# AngularJS conditional directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
myDirective.directive('sidebar', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<li ng-repeat="m in menu"><a href="{{m.url}}"><i class="{{m.image}}"></i> {{m.name}}</a></li>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.menu = [
        {
          "name": "Home",
          "url": "/",
          "image": "fa fa-bar-chart-o"
        },
        {
          "name": "Data Integration",
          "url": "/manage/dataintegration/index",
          "image": "fa fa-dashboard"
        },
        {
          "name": "Users",
          "url": "/manage/users/index",
          "image": "fa fa-dashboard"
        },
        {
          "name": "Logger",
          "url": "/manage/logger/index",
          "image": "fa fa-dashboard"
        },
        {
          "name": "Drop",
          "url": "",
          "image": "fa fa-dashboard",
          "submenu": [
            {
              "name": "Logger",
              "url": "/manage/logger/index",
              "image": "fa fa-dashboard"
            },
            {
              "name": "Logger2",
              "url": "/manage/logger/index",
              "image": "fa fa-dashboard"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]

    }
  }
});
```

Is it possible to somehow apply an `ng-if` within the template in a way that will allow me to know if the current menu item has a `submenu` element and therefore change the template accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your template

```
template: '<li ng-repeat="m in menu">' + 
            '<a href="{{m.url}}"><i class="{{m.image}}"></i> {{m.name}}</a>' +
            '<ul ng-if="m.submenu">' +
               '<li ng-repeat="sm in m.submenu">' +
                '<a href="{{sm.url}}"><i class="{{sm.image}}"></i> {{sm.name}}</a>' +
               '</li>' +
            '</ul>' +
           '</li>',
```

haven't tried the above. some tweaks might be needed.